# How can I override the extended keyboard toolbar on the iOS 9 virtual keyboard?

Tags: uikit, ios9, virtual-keyboard

The virtual keyboard in iOS 9 brings undo, redo, and paste controls.  I notice that in my app, they're always the same but in Safari and others, they're different with customizations.  I have a custom toolbar already as the `inputAccessoryView` and I'd rather have it there than the iOS supplied controls.  I've looked around but I can't see anything that allows for overriding it with my view.  Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I found this post, but uses a private API call as a workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31317062/accessory-bar-hiding-in-ios-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Luke's comment to the original post, he described UITextInputAssistantItem as a private API. It's true this class does not yet appear in the iOS 9 SDK documentation, but it does appear in the [iOS 9 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html), and was introduced at WWDC ([session 107](http://asciiwwdc.com/2015/sessions/107); search for "assistant"), so it seems okay to use and discuss.

Here's some [sample code](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/37863#37863) provided by an Apple employee on their public forum:

```
NSArray barButtonItems = @[ /* Create UIBarButtonItems and place them here */ ];  
UIBarButtonItem representativeItem = // This is optional, if present when there isn't enough room on the bar, the group will be replaced with this item  
UIBarButtonItemGroup *group = [[UIBarButtonItemGroup alloc] initWithBarButtonItems:barButtonItems representativeItem:representativeItem]  
textView.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[ group ]; // replace the items on the bar. Alternatively you can append this group and get the default leading items with this extra group
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I came across the same solution on the developer forums, so therefore ou get the right answer.